# Is my password storage technique strong enough

Tags: asp.net, security, passwords

This is a question about whether my security process is adequate for the kind of information i am storing.

I am building a website using **ASP.NET 4.0 with a SQL** backend and need to know how my security would hold up with regards to passwords and hashes etc.

I don't store any critical information on someone - No `real names, addresses, credit card` details or anything like that... just `email and username`.

For now, I am deliberately leaving out some specifics as I am not sure if telling you them will **weaken my security** but if not I can reveal slightly more.

Here is how I do it:

1. The user registers with their email and a unique username up to `50 chars` long
2. They create a password (minimum `6 chars)` using any characters on the keyboard (I HTMLEncode the input and am using `parameterized` stored procedures so I don't restrict the chars)
3. I send them an email with a link to verify they are real.
4. I use FormsAuthentication to set an auth cookie but I'm not using `SSL` at the moment... I understand the implications of sending auth details across plain `http` but I have asked my host to add the cert so it should be ready shortly.

It's the hashing bit I need to be sure of!

I create a random `100` character salt from the following char set (I just use the System.Random class, nothing **`cryptographic`**) - `abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!£$%^*()_{}[]@~#<,>.?`

This is then merged with the password and then hashed using **`SHA-512 (SHA512Managed class)`** tens of thousands of times (takes nearly **`2 seconds on my i7 laptop`** to generate the final hash).

This final hash is then converted to a `base64` string and compared with the already-hashed password in the database (the salt is stored in another column in the DB too)

A few questions (ignore the lack of `SSL` for the moment, I just haven't bought the certificate yet but it will be ready in a week or so):

1. Does this strike you as secure enough? I understand there are degrees of security and that given enough time and resources anything is breakable but given that I don't store critical data, does it seem like enough?
2. Would revealing the actual number of times I hash the password weaken my security?
3. Does a `100` character salt make any difference over, say, a `20` character one?
4. By revealing how I join a password and **`salt`** together, would that weaken my security?

Comment: I would say hashing so many times does not really contribute to the security. If you want to do it anyway, check this page to prevent hurting yourself: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/115406/is-it-more-secure-to-hash-a-password-multiple-times

Comment: You might get better answers at http://security.stackexchange.com/...

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin it most definitely contributes to the security - it makes brute forcing the hashes way slower. Also, the link you provided has really poor answers - just stick with a good known hashing scheme, like __bcrypt__, and everything is fine.

Comment: @sAnS Thanks for your efforts to improve SO by editing posts. However, [there's really no reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158564/169503) for the arbitrary bold emphasis you seem to [introduce](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2203834) [in](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2203826) [various](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2203822) [posts](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2203761). It only introduces noise and can actually be considered actively harmful.

Comment: @Xavi López thanks for the note i just tried to point out the objectives in the posts.i will try to point out only the coding part next time.Also can you point me some scenario where we need to use bold emphasis in the posts..

Comment: @sAnS format editing is alright, as is every edit that fixes all issues in a post and improves clarity without changing the original meaning. In the end, the issue here is reviewers accepting those edits.

Answer (score 4):

So, let's try to answer your questions one by one:

### *Does this strike you as secure enough? I understand there are degrees of security and that given enough time and resources anything is breakable but given that I don't store critical data, does it seem like enough?*

No. It is **definitely** not "secure enough".

Without seeing code, it's hard to say more. But the fact that you're doing a straight `SHA512` instead of doing a HMAC indicates one problem. Not because you need to be using a HMAC, but because most algorithms that are designed for this purpose use HMAC under the hood (for several reasons).

And it seems likely you're doing `hash = SHA512(hash)` (just from your wording) which is proven to be bad.

So without seeing code, it's hard to say for sure, but it's not pointing in the right direction...

### *Would revealing the actual number of times I hash the password weaken my security?*

No, it shouldn't. If it does, you have a problem somewhere else in the algorithm.

### *Does a 100 character salt make any difference over, say, a 20 character one?*

Nope. All the salt does is make the hash unique (forcing the attacker to attack each password separately). All you need is a salt long enough to be statistically unique. Thanks to the [Birthday Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem), 128 bits is more than enough for a 1/10^12 chance of collision. Which is plenty for us. So that means that 16 characters is the upper bound on salt effectiveness.

That doesn't mean it's *bad* to use a longer salt. It just means that making it longer than 16 characters doesn't significantly increase the security it provides...

### *By revealing how I join a password and salt together, would that weaken my security?*

If it does, your algorithm is severely flawed. If it does, it amounts to [Security Through Obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity).

## The Real Answer

The real answer here is to not re-invent the wheel. Algorithms like PBKDF2 and BCRYPT exist for exactly this purpose. So use them.

## Further Information (Note that these talk about PHP, but the concepts are 100% applicable to ASP.NET and C#):

- [YouTube Video - Password Storage and Hacking in PHP](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T4NTdRvIrdk)
- [Blog Post - The Rainbow Table Is Dead](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2011/08/rainbow-table-is-dead.html)
- [Blog Post - Properly Salting Passwords](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2012/04/properly-salting-passwords-case-against.html)
- [PHP password_hash RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/password_hash)
- [Blog Post - Seven Ways To Screw Up BCrypt](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2012/12/seven-ways-to-screw-up-bcrypt.html)

Comment: How does an HMAC make things more secure? There's no message to authenticate here.

Comment: @BillyONeal: By itself, making it a HMAC won't make it more secure. However, algorithms that are designed for this (such as PBKDF2 and the like) are typically designed using HMACs to prevent length extension bugs and increase the number of hash rounds per cycle...

Comment: Ok then, I agree with that. But then the proper answer isn't "you're not using an HMAC" it is "you're not using an algorithm designed to achieve the goal you want".

Answer (score 2):

1. In theory, your hashing scheme sounds ok. In practice, it sounds like you have [rolled your own crypto](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/18197/20774), which is bad. Use [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt), [scrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt), or [pbkdf2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2). All of these are designed by security professionals.
2. Not really, but I don't think anyone needs to know that anyway.
3. No. It just needs to be unique to every user. The purpose of salt is to prevent precalculation of hashes/rainbow table attacks.
4. This doesn't apply once you make use of bcrypt (or scrypt or pbkdf2)

http://security.stackexchange.com has some topics on the subject, you should check them out.

Some extra notes - serious attackers will crack sha512 hashes way faster than your laptop. For example you could rent a server with a few Tesla GPU's from Amazon or similar, and start cracking at a few billion hashes/second rate. Scrypt makes some effort trying to prevent this by using memory intensive operations.

6 characters minimum for password is not enough, go with at least 8. A related image, I haven't verified the times but it gives a rough estimate and gives you the general idea (excluding dictionary attacks, which can target longer passwords):
[image: Password cracking times]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I suppose I did roll my own but at least I used recognized crypto techniques and didn't try to come up with my own :). I am going to look into Bcrypt and see how that works.

Comment: Note that that complexity table is only for "brute force" approaches -- real passwords (made by humans) are generally not uniformly random which means that they can be broken faster than this.

Comment: @BillyONeal good point, it doesn't apply to any sort of dictionary attack. Fixed the answer to include that.